# Unable to configure a new agent : Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04

We had some 12 agents (vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.188.4) running on one Az VM (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS) as processes (`./config.sh && screen ./run.sh`). All was well..

I had to run some command related to /tmp folder but it kept showing busy and we suspected that our Agents might be using /tmp. Unfortunately instead of any other clean way of stopping the agents, we killed all processes on this VM manually, including the agents'.

After the /tmp related command ran successfully, I tried running `screen ./run.sh` from one of the agent directories. And I got an error:

`Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005`

I also had tried :

`.agent2/run.sh` and I got the error :

```
ldd: ./bin/libcoreclr.so: No such file or directory
ldd: ./bin/System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.so: No such file or directory
ldd: ./bin/System.IO.Compression.Native.so: No such file or directory
ldd: ./bin/System.Net.Http.Native.so: No such file or directory
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80004005
```

I even downloaded a new .tar for the agent and ran a fresh `./config` . But I get the same error on `./config` as well

Is there a solution to this? Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

export COMPlus_EnableDiagnostics = 0, and then running ./config from the agent directory. worked!

Comment: I can confirm this solution - Without setting this variable the agent is trying to enable some kind of debugging mode which will need sudo access. I assume this can be fixed by installing the debugging tools correctly but not sure what is needed for that.

Comment: More information can be found here https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/10217#issuecomment-462323277.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when running as the non-privileged user specified in the systemd file but running as root user worked fine.

Finally used:

```
strace -f -o trace.log /<executable path>/<executable name>
```

Which led me to:

```
9183  mknod("/tmp/clr-debug-pipe-9183-8112345738-in", S_IFIFO|0700) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

This caused me to compare the /tmp directory between working and non-working boxes.

```
[<not-working-hostname>]$ ll /
drwxrwxr-x   7 root root   93 Jan  5 21:37 tmp

[<working-hostname>]$ ll /
drwxrwxrwt   7 root root   93 Jan  5 21:59 tmp
```

(Note the r-x vs rwt)

Fix:

```
[<hostname>]# chmod 1777 /tmp
```